# JSONP-like cross-origin procedure: use JSON array response

Tags: javascript, json, cross-domain, jsonp

I need to access a page on another domain, which returns as response a JSON array:

```
[{"name":"value","x":"y"},{"name":"value","x":"y"}]
```

Due to the cross-origin rule, I can't get this data through an XMLHttpRequest. Apparently I have to use a JSONP-like procedure:

- Add script element to the page's body, with the src attribute poiting to the page
- The browser does the HTTP request and gets the data

I can not edit the remote page/the response. The remote page is not meant to be accessed that way (so I can't use a JSONP callback parameter).
The remote page also requires the use of a specific cookie.
How can I access the data that has been just retrieved?

Comment: If the service does not support CORS or JSONP, you can't. You have to use the serverside to get the data and do an ajax call to your own server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly the case the same origin policy exists for. Any possible solution would mean a security hole. If the data server unable to wrap it in your callback function, you have to proxy this through your own server-side app.

Comment: I guess I'll proxy it. Thanks anyway.